# express stylesheet/javascript linking, how does it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Simple question

we have this link in the index.ejs

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
```

Well there is no stylesheets/style.css in the current Views folder, this doesn't make sense, shouldnt it be more like.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../public/stylesheets/style.css'/>
```

I'm assuming its just express magic handling everything at this point.

Comment: Presumably, you have a line in your server code telling it to serve up static content. [You can read the official website](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for more information. In short, yes, it's express doing some magic.

Comment: Haha, i thought so, thanks a lot that answered my question